# How do I textile and sanitize html?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, escaping, textile

Now i ran into some stupid situation. I want the users to be able to use textile, but they shouldn't mess around with my valid HTML around their entry. So I have to escape the HTML somehow.

- `html_escape(textilize("</body>Foo"))` would break textile while
- `textilize(html_escape("</body>Foo"))` would work, but breaks various Textile features like links (written like `"Linkname":http://www.wheretogo.com/`), since the quotes would be transformed into `&quot;` and thus not detected by textile anymore.
- `sanitize` doesn't do a better job.

Any suggestions on that one? I would prefer not to use *Tidy* for this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For those who run into the same problem: If you are using the **RedCloth gem** you can just define your own method (in one of your helpers).

```
def safe_textilize( s )
  if s && s.respond_to?(:to_s)
    doc = RedCloth.new( s.to_s )
    doc.filter_html = true
    doc.to_html
  end
end
```

Excerpt from the Documentation:

> Accessors for setting security restrictions.
>
> This is a nice thing if you‘re using RedCloth for formatting in
>   public places (e.g.  Wikis) where you don‘t want users to abuse HTML for bad things.
>
> If `filter_html` is set, HTML which wasn‘t created by the Textile processor will be
>   escaped. Alternatively, if `sanitize_html` is set, HTML can pass through the Textile
>   processor but unauthorized tags and attributes will be removed.

Comment: But beware of pre and code tag exploits. eg. (dare I risk this?) <pre onmouseover="alert('Gotcha!')">!!!!mouse trap!!!!</pre>

Answer (score 2):

This works for me and guards against every XSS attack I've tried including onmouse... handlers in pre and code blocks:

```
<%= RedCloth.new( sanitize( @comment.body ), [:filter_html, :filter_styles, :filter_classes, :filter_ids] ).to_html -%>
```

The initial sanitize removes a lot of potential XSS exploits including mouseovers.

As far as I can tell :filter_html escapes most html tags apart from code and pre. The other filters are there because I don't want users applying any classes, ids and styles.

I just tested my comments page with your example

```
"</body>Foo"
```

and it completely removed the rogue body tag

I am using Redcloth version 4.2.3 and Rails version 2.3.5

Answer (score 0):

Looks like textile simply doesn't support what you want.

You really want to only allow a carefully controlled subset of HTML, but textile is designed to allow arbitrary HTML. I don't think you can use textile at all in this situation (unless it supports that kind of restriction).

What you need is probably a special "restricted" version of textile, that only allows "safe" markup (defining that however might already be tricky). I do not know if that exists, however.

You might have a look at [BBCode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bbcode), that allows to restrict the possible markup.

Comment: There's also Markdown (which Stack Overflow uses), http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/

Comment: Yea, thought about markdown, too. But AFAIK stackoverflow does additional escaping (some blogpost of Jeff pointed that out). Markdown also allows arbitrary HTML.

Comment: @David Zaslavsky: 
Read from the official website (http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#overview): "For any markup that is not covered by Markdown’s syntax, you simply use HTML itself."

Comment: @Vanuan: True, but I don't need to be instructed to read the official website. Besides, some Markdown implementations offer a "safe mode" which will sanitize HTML in the input.