# Django : sanitize HTML and Textile

Tags: python, django, formatting, escaping, textile

I would like to be able to sanitize the HTML tags of an input (from a form for instance, so that users don't mess up with HTML tags), but allow users to do some formatting through Textile (django.contrib.markup). Example below.

I have tried to escape the content in a filter before I Textil-ize it, like this `{{ data|escape|textile }}`, but it doesn't work, it seems as if Textile un-escapes escaped characters.

How should I do?

Example of what I want to do:

- Enter the following in my form :

  > <b>Bold with HTML tag ; should be escaped </b>
  >   *Bold with textile tag; should appear bold*
- Result I would like to see in my template:

  > <b>Bold with HTML tag ; should be escaped </b>
  >   **Bold with textile tag; should appear bold**

For the record, it is similar to this thread, but for Django:
[How do I textile and sanitize html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501737/how-do-i-textile-and-sanitize-html?rq=1)