# RedCloth and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redcloth

I want use RedCloth gem, 
i install it, in my gemfile i put -> gem 'RedCloth'
in my show.html.erb i put ->

```
<%= RedCloth.new(@post.text).to_html %>
```

and i saw simple html syntax, than i use

```
<%= raw RedCloth.new(@post.text).to_html %>
```

and it work perfect, it's not safe
@post.text -> puts by some user

and when i put `<script> alert('!!!') </script>` i saw "!!!" in alert

How to use RedCloth safely ( or recomend another gem )

Comment: Check this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501737/how-do-i-textile-and-sanitize-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sanitize gem https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize/ is a solid choice for whitelisting only certain html elements and blocking others (eg )